# Line extending below chart area in multi-pane Highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

I am having a problem with Highstock. I have a multi-pane chart (multiple charts stacked on top of each other). When I specify a min and max value for the y-axis, if any value in the series is less than the min value, it will extend below the chart, usually extending into the chart below. For some reason, the same is not true for when a data point is above the max value. I can't tell if this is a bug in Highstock or just something I am doing wrong.

I understand that this is an unusual use case for Highstock, but it is necessary for the application I am developing. The only example I can find for multi-pane charts with Highstock is on their demo page at http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume, but that is a different situation.

Please see my example: http://jsfiddle.net/afoster777/UJaJG/

Here is my configuration:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    alignTicks: false,
    plotOptions: {
        shadow: false,
        series: {
            connectNulls: false
        },
        plotBorderColor: "#CCCCCC",
        plotBorderWidth: 2,
        plotBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    }
},
navigator: {
    enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Time'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: false
},
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: "Y"
    },
    min: 0.8,
    max: 0.9,
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -6,
        y: 3
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    height: 250,
    offset: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
}, {
    title: {
        text: "Y"
    },
    min: 0.8,
    max: 0.9,
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -6,
        y: 3
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    top: 320,
    height: 250,
    offset: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
}],
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    id: 0,
    name: 'Series1',
    yAxis: 0,
    data: series1data,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    gapSize: 2,
    connectNulls: false
}, {
    type: 'line',
    id: 1,
    name: 'Series2',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: series2data,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    gapSize: 2,
    connectNulls: false
}]
});
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Edit: Apparently there is an open issue about this already (Issue# 1387). Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently github user sappling has made a fix for this problem and submitted a pull request. I included sappling's version of Highstock `<script src="http://raw.github.com/sappling/highcharts.com/clip/js/highstock.src.js"></script>` instead of the vanilla one, and the problem seems to be fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/afoster777/jEZ9w/

Comment: Here is a link to sappling's pull request: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/pull/1317